# alguem tem ideia do porquê o if não ser executado?

Tags: c, string

```c
if (strcmp(letra4, "[") == 0) {
  char string_sem_colchete[10];
  for(i=1; i<strlen(comando4)-1; i++)
  {
    string_sem_colchete[i-1] = comando4[i];
  }

  string_sem_colchete[i-1] = '\0';
  numero4 = atoi(string_sem_colchete);
  printf("%i", numero4);
}
```

Em resumo a variável `letra4` é a primeira posição de uma `string`, se caso o caractere dessa posição seja "[", ele executará esse código dentro do `if` para retirar o primeiro e o último caractere dessa `string` e converter em `int`. O código funciona, o problema é q o IF aparenta não ser executado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciona que **a variável `letra4` é a primeira posição de uma string, acredito que esteja querendo comparar `char`s**. Se for esse o caso, comparar os valores diretamente deveria ser suficiente (note que estou usando aspas simples, isso denota o tipo `char` e não `string`):

`if (letra4 == '[') {`

A comparação que está tentando fazer com `strcmp` atualmente deveria receber dois ponteiros (strings ou `char*`) em sua chamada. Funcionaria caso estivesse passando `char*` (apenas como um exemplo, lembre-se de alocar e liberar a memória usada):

`char* letra4 = "[";`

Utilizando **ponteiros e não `char`**, você pode fazer a comparação com `strcmp`.

---

E caso sua `string` seja um `array` de `char`s literal:

`char letra4[20] = {/*...*/};`

Pode comparar apenas a primeira posição do seu `array`:

`if (letra4[0] == '[') {`

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: nossa eu não tinha ideia de que aspas simples era pra char e aspas duplas era pra strings, pra mim era tudo a mesma coisa kkkkkkkkkk

muito obrigado, vou ver se funciona aq

Comment: eu tentei usar aspas simples, tentei comparar a outra string com posições [0], [1], [2]... mas nada, aí eu tentei fazer um simples if(letra4 == '['){} e aparentemente funcionou kkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Você só quer comparar o primeiro char? `strcmp` compara a string inteira. Só passaria no if se sua string fosse só `"["`.

Compare só a primeira posição: `if (letra4[0] == '[')`... Isso imaginando que letra4 seja ou um vetor ou um ponteiro, pois você deixou o mistério no ar né?

Comment: isso, eu já tentei fazer isso, mas não foi tbm, aí eu armazenei o primeiro caractere de outra string no char letra4, eu printo essa variavel e aparece "[", por isso eu não tenho a miníma ideia do porque o if não ser executado

Answer (score 0):

Se não está entrando no IF, acredito que 'letra4' está apresentando outro valor.
Tente colocar breakpoint e acessar o conteudo dessa variavel.

Caso tenha duvidas sobre a doc do 'strcmp':
http://linguagemc.com.br/a-biblioteca-string-h/

Comment: tipo assim, letra4 é o primeiro caractere de uma string... letra4 = comando[0], eu printo a variável letra4, e oq aparece é "[", por isso que eu não tenho ideia do porquê o if não ser executado

Comment: Nesse caso voce tem um char.... e nao um char[]... voce poderia fazer o if assim:
if (letra4 == '[' ), com aspas simples... talvez esteja ai seu problema.